# Broken pipe error Flask

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

Я использую приложение Flask + uwsgi.
Сервер работает, но через 5 минут я получаю

```
[pid: 6607|app: 0|req: 8/108] 157.230.31.163 () {42 vars in 1026 bytes} [Wed Aug 25 11:48:37 2021] POST /bot/restart => generated 3 bytes in 13690 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 78 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
DAMN ! worker 5 (pid: 6611) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
[pid: 6610|app: 0|req: 31/109] 157.230.31.163 () {36 vars in 1008 bytes} [Wed Aug 25 11:49:28 2021] GET / => generated 218 bytes in 6170 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 4 headers in 142 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
Respawned uWSGI worker 5 (new pid: 17910)
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
```

config.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
master = true
http-socket = 0.0.0.0:5000
processes = 5
die-on-term = true
```

run.py

```
from app import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(app.run('0.0.0.0', int(5000), debug=True))
```

init.py

```
from flask_login import LoginManager
from app.models import db, login


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://...'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.secret_key = '...'
login.init_app(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
db.init_app(app)


@app.before_first_request
def create_table():
    db.create_all()

from app import routes

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def lionel():
    return render_template('index.jinja2')
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, минимальный пример кода и полный стек с ошибкой

Comment: @gil9red, добавил

Comment: Гугление текста ошибки приводит к https://stackoverflow.com/q/26692284/5909792, исключение BrokenPipeError. И как я понимаю, это не страшное исключение. Вот еще по этой теме https://python-forum.io/thread-3634.html

Comment: Подскажите, где мне в коде обернуть это в try-except

Comment: Это внутренностях какой-то библиотеки, поэтому хз :) У вас приложение падает от этого?

Comment: да, сигнал killed

Comment: Почитайте dmesg, вдруг там OOM Killer убивает ваш процесс